# Saturated Measures -- an issue with wording

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working on a homework problem and the phrasing of the question has me in a bit of a bind. The question is excerpted from Folland (1.16c) below:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. A set $E\subset X$ is called **locally measurable** if $E\cap A \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $A \in M$ such that $\mu(A) < \infty$. Let $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ be the collection of all locally measurable sets. Clearly $\mathcal{M} \subset \widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$; if $\mathcal{M} = \widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$, then $\mu$ is called **saturated**.
>
> ...
>
> c.) Define $\widetilde{\mu}$ on $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ by $\widetilde{\mu}(E) = \mu(E)$ if $E \in \mathcal{M}$ and $\widetilde{\mu}(E) = \infty$ otherwise. Then $\widetilde{\mu}$ is a saturated measure on $\widetilde{M}$, called the **saturation** of $\mu$.

My confusion: are we trying to extend $\mu$ and show that this extension is saturated, or are we considering a totally new measure space $(X,\widetilde{\mathcal{M}},\widetilde{\mu})$ with the definitions given in part (c) as listed above? In other words, when considering whether a set is locally measurable, are we considering it with respect to $\mu$ and $\mathcal{M}$ or $\widetilde{\mu}$ and $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$... or does it matter?

Comment: You are considering a new measure space $(X,\widetilde{\mathcal{M}},\widetilde{\mu})$. In (c) $\widetilde{\mu}$ is saturated applying the definition of saturated to $\widetilde{\mu}$. The point of (c) is to show that all locally measurable sets in $Y$ are already in $\widetilde{M}$. But notice that since the definition of locally measurable involves looking at sets of finite measure $\mu$ and $\widetilde{\mu}$ are equal there.

Comment: @Pp.. what's $Y$?

Comment: Forgot to change it. $Y$ is supposed to denote $(X,\widetilde{\mathcal{M}},\widetilde{\mu})$.

Comment: @Pp.. Thanks. I will think a little on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to prove that $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\widetilde{\mu}$ is a measure on it. This one is walking straight from the definitions.

The prove $\widetilde{\mu}$ is saturated:

Take $E\subset X$ and assume that $E\cap A\in\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ for all $A\in\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ with $\widetilde{\mu}(A)<\infty$. Since $\widetilde{\mu}(A)<\infty$, we must have $A\in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(A)=\widetilde{\mu}(A)<\infty$. Since $E\cap A\in\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ we have that $(E\cap A)\cap B\in \mathcal{M}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(B)<\infty$. In particular it is true for $B:=A$. Therefore $E\cap A\in M$. Hence $E$ is locally measurable for $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, and therefore $E\in\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ already.